# "id" turn red when i updated Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-resources

I have some problem with my Android Studio. After i updated, "id" and all other link to resource turning red.
I try to rebuild or restart my Android Studio but its not working. I really need some help.

[image: this is whats it look like]

Comment: I had a similar error. I did invalidCashStudio.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfWNF.png

Comment: oh I had to reinstall it a few minutes ago, I have a lot of works to do with it so I cant wait but thank you for your comment, I will do this if this error occurs